# How to add QSerialPort library in QT4.8.7

Tags: qt, serial-port

For an Embedded based project, I need to use `QT4.8.7`. I installed the QT 4.8.7 cross compiler in /usr/local/ directory. As QT4.8.7 do not have support QSerialPort, I am having hard time dealing with it. But as per this [article](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Serial_Port) we can add the QSerialPort library support in QT4.8.7.

I am following the points mentioned below the heading `Build and Install from QtCreator` but the problem is, in the first point they have mentioned to download and unpack the QSerialPort source but at the link there is no downloadable file. I also didn't get the point no. 4 which says

`add a new make "Build Step" and write to the "Make arguments" the install target`

Can anyone please explain these points.

Answer (score 1):

In the articles there are links to Qt Serial Port git repo:
[git://code.qt.io/qt/qtserialport.git](http://git://code.qt.io/qt/qtserialport.git)

Alternatively you can find tarballs on Qt download server for each release e.g http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.8/5.8.0/submodules/qtserialport-opensource-src-5.8.0.tar.gz

---

About the build instructions, if you followed the steps, it is pretty clear.

> add a new make "Build Step" and write to the "Make arguments" the **install** target

requests you to add a new build step to the list of build steps, this new build step should be a "Make" build step. And within the field "Make arguments" of this new build step add "install".

Again its pretty clear once you are in Qt Creator in the right page.

Also you can take a look at Qt Creator documentation ofr more details:
http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html#build-steps

Comment: The link `http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.8/5.8.0/submodules/qtserialport-opensource-src-5.8.0.tar.gz` downloads the QTSerialPort 5.8. Is it the same which we have to download to enable support for qt4.8.7

Comment: I downloaded the qtserialport 5.8. from the link you mentioned and while re building it gives error `Use atleast qt5.0.0 or try to download qtserialport for qt4`

Comment: @user46573544 The link I provided is just an example. You may have to look around for different tarballs for different Qt versions. Also there is a `qt4-dev` branch in the official git repo.

Comment: @user46573544 See https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Serial_Port#Getting_the_source_code